# OWASP ZAP docker returns 'Connection refused' when running active-scan

Tags: docker, owasp, zap

I'm trying to set up OWASP ZAP to run locally using the docker image provided.

```
docker run --name zap -u zap \
-p 8090:8090 -v "$(pwd)/reports":/zap/reports/:rw \
-i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0 \
-config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true \
-config api.disablekey=true
```

If I try and run a quick-scan, it completes successfully

```
docker exec zap zap-cli --verbose quick-scan --self-contained --start-options '-config api.disablekey=true' http://www.itsecgames.com -l Medium
```

but I keep getting `Connection refused` every-time I try an active-scan

```
docker exec zap zap-cli --verbose active-scan http://www.itsecgames.com
```

Any idea why this might be the case?

I get the same error when trying to generate reports:

```
docker exec zap zap-cli --verbose report -o /zap/reports/owasp-quick-scan-report.html --output-format html
```

EDIT:
and the logs don't show any useful information:

```
9864 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | TestPersistentXSSAttack in 0.003s with 0 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
9864 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | TestSQLInjection strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
10350 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | TestSQLInjection in 0.486s with 22 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
10350 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | CodeInjectionPlugin strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
10522 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | CodeInjectionPlugin in 0.172s with 8 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
10522 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | CommandInjectionPlugin strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
11355 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | CommandInjectionPlugin in 0.833s with 32 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
11355 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | TestDirectoryBrowsing strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
11389 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | TestDirectoryBrowsing in 0.034s with 1 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
11389 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | TestExternalRedirect strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
11579 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | TestExternalRedirect in 0.19s with 9 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
11580 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | BufferOverflow strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
11617 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | BufferOverflow in 0.037s with 1 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
11617 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | FormatString strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
11729 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | FormatString in 0.112s with 3 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
11729 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | TestInjectionCRLF strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
11911 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | TestInjectionCRLF in 0.182s with 7 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
11912 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | TestParameterTamper strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
12106 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://www.itsecgames.com | TestParameterTamper in 0.194s with 7 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
12106 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://www.itsecgames.com | ScriptsActiveScanner strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
12107 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - skipped plugin [no scripts enabled] http://www.itsecgames.com | ScriptsActiveScanner in 0.001s with 0 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
12107 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host http://www.itsecgames.com in 6.389s
12108 [Thread-8] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.Scanner  - scanner completed in 6.402s
16868 [Thread-27] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.Scanner  - scanner stopped
16887 [Thread-27] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache commit start
16891 [Thread-27] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache commit end
16895 [Thread-27] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - Database closed
16996 [Thread-27] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.CoreAPI  - OWASP ZAP 2.7.0 terminated.
```

Comment: The ZAP command line options look right. Are there any errors in the zap.log file?

Comment: @SimonBennetts I have edited my question to include the end of the zap.log but no, no error or info why the scan failed is shown

Comment: I suspect its a zap-cli problem then - thats maintained by a 3rd party. You could just use the packaged full scan which should give you more control: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Full-Scan

Answer (score 2):

I myself was entangled with this issue. I'm not sure if it happened with you too, but going through the Python errors, I saw that zap-cli was trying to connect to the proxy at port 8080 instead of 8090. Here's how I got everything to work:

1. I started the ZAP daemon by changing the port to 8080.

```
docker run --rm -u zap -p 8090:8080 -d owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.disablekey=true
```

2. Ran `open-url`

```
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME/ID> zap-cli open-url <TARGET>
```

3. Lastly, I ran the scan

```
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME/ID> zap-cli active-scan <TARGET>
```